# When does user_tab_columns get updated?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, ddl, alter

In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40301599/plsql-get-table-in-before-alter-trigger) I tried to create a hist table, which keeps a log from the given table. With the answers in that question, I tried to create something new.

Since it is not possible to create a system trigger on tables or views, I created a DDL trigger like this:

```
create or replace trigger ident_hist_trig after alter on schema
declare
    v_table varchar2(30);
begin
    select upper(ora_dict_obj_name) into v_table from dual;
    if (v_table = 'Z_IDENT') then
        prc_create_hist_tabel('z_ident_hist', 'z_ident');
    elsif (v_table = 'D_IDENT') then
        prc_create_hist_tabel('d_ident_hist', 'd_ident');
    elsif (v_table = 'X_IDENT') then
        prc_create_hist_tabel('x_ident_hist', 'x_ident');
    else
        null;
    end if;
end;
/
```

The procedure prc_create_hist_tabel looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure prc_create_hist_tabel(p_naam_hist_tabel in varchar2, p_naam_tabel in varchar2) is
    cursor c is 
        select 'alter table ' || p_naam_hist_tabel || ' add ' || column_name || ' ' || data_type || case when data_type = 'DATE' then null else '(' || data_length || ')' end lijn 
        from user_tab_columns 
        where TABLE_NAME = upper(p_naam_tabel) 
        and column_name not in (select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = upper(p_naam_hist_tabel));
    v_dummy number(1);
    cursor trig is
        select column_name || ',' kolom, ':old.' || column_name || ',' old
        from user_tab_columns
        where table_name = upper(p_naam_tabel);
    v_trigger_sql varchar2(32767);
begin
    begin
        select 1 into v_dummy
        from user_tab_columns
        where TABLE_NAME = upper(p_naam_hist_tabel)
        group by 1;
    exception when no_data_found then
        execute immediate 'create table ' || p_naam_hist_tabel || ' (wijziger varchar2(60) default user, wijzigdatum date default sysdate, constraint pk_' || p_naam_hist_tabel || ' primary key (wijziger, wijzigdatum))';
    end;
    dbms_output.put_line('BBB');
    for i in c
    loop
        begin
            dbms_output.put_line(i.lijn);
            execute immediate i.lijn;
        exception when others then
            dbms_output.put_line(i.lijn);
        end;
    end loop;

    v_trigger_sql := 'create or replace trigger ' || p_naam_tabel || '_hist_trig after update on ' || p_naam_tabel || ' for each row begin insert into ' || p_naam_hist_tabel || ' (';
    for v_lijn in trig
    loop
        v_trigger_sql := v_trigger_sql || v_lijn.kolom;
    end loop;
    v_trigger_sql := substr(v_trigger_sql, 1, length(v_trigger_sql) - 1);
    v_trigger_sql := v_trigger_sql || ') values (';
    for v_lijn in trig
    loop
        v_trigger_sql := v_trigger_sql || v_lijn.old;
    end loop;
    v_trigger_sql := substr(v_trigger_sql, 1, length(v_trigger_sql) - 1);
    v_trigger_sql := v_trigger_sql || '); end;';

    execute immediate v_trigger_sql;
end;
/
```

In short what that function does, is maintain the history table. If it doesn't exist, it will create one, and if it exists, it will add the new columns to it. The procedure also creates a new trigger which will write the old values into the history table after update.

But when I alter one of the tables x_ident, z_ident or d_ident, the cursor c will return nothing (I can check that with the print when I loop through it). Although when execute the select **after** I altered my table, then I do get results.

The results I get from altering the table d_ident are these:

```
BBB

d_ident: Table altered.
```

But I guess it should be the other way around, I think that the procedure prc_create_hist_tabel is executed before the alter table actually goes off,  and I guess I should get something like this:

```
d_ident: Table altered.

BBB
```

Any help would be apreciated. I tried to create a trigger on insert on user_tab_columns, but that gave me ORA-25001: cannot create this trigger type on views.

I tried with a sleep command as well, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work.  Even if you were able to get the column that is being added to the table in your trigger, if you tried to actually do DDL in a trigger, you'd get an error that DDL isn't allowed in a trigger.

I'd expect that the right way to approach this would be to make the call to `prc_create_hist_tabel` as part of your promotion scripts.  Reasonable systems don't add columns to tables willy-nilly.  The DDL is part of a promotion that exists in source control and gets deployed after testing.  If your promotion scripts failed to modify the history table, you'd find out during testing that you missed a step and the change would never go to production.  Having changes happen automatically means that they're not in change control which makes it more difficult to do a build from change control.

If you are determined to do this automatically, your trigger would need to submit a job, realistically using `dbms_job` not the newer `dbms_scheduler`, that calls the procedure.  That job would run after the transaction the DDL trigger is a part of committed.  At that point, the column would be visible in `dba_tab_columns`.  And your job is free to do DDL.